# loadHTMLString and "thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=exc_i386_gpflt)"

Tags: swift

Well, I'm not sure it is a real problem but it is unpleasant to see an error. The "thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=exc_i386_gpflt)" error appears with a probability of about 50% in simulator. But there is no error in real device.
I tried to use optionals, but without a noticeable result.
I have only WKWebView and a Button. The code is:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var WebView: WKWebView!

    let all = ["kjhgjhkg","qqqqqqqqq", "wwwwwwwww", "lllllllll", "bbbbbbbb"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 
 WebView.loadHTMLString("<h1>The first title</h1>", baseURL: nil)   
    }
 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func btnRefresh(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let RandomNomber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(all.count)))
//    let myString = all[RandomNomber]
//     let myString2 = "<h1>" + myString + "</h1>"
            WebView.loadHTMLString("<h1>" + all[RandomNomber] + "</h1>", baseURL: nil) 
    }
}
```

Comment: reset your simulator and check

Comment: @this.girish no this don't work. The reboot of macbook don't work as well. Per 10 launches of simulator it crushed 4 times immediately after the first click of the button. The other 6 times it worked well.

Comment: How did you get the WKWebView to be an outlet? It's not in the object library

Comment: @JovanJovanovski , O, I supposed, that it could be the reason of problem. I made an outlet for UIWebView and replaced "UI" with "WK".

Comment: Did this fix your problem? And I highly recommend that you start naming your variables and constants with small letters.

Comment: @JovanJovanovski , thank you for advice. This name is practically an exception. But about fixing problem I didn't understand, what should I do to fix it.

Comment: @JovanJovanovski well, I replaced "WK" with  "UI", and now the simulator do not crush at all. Thank you. But I'm not sure if using of UIWebView is a good idea, because of this: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview                               "Note
In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWebView class instead of using UIWebView. Additionally, consider setting the WKPreferences property javaScriptEnabled to false if you render files that are not supposed to run JavaScript."

Comment: The choice to use WKWebView or UIWebView is completely yours. It's just that if you decide to use WKWebView you must create it programmatically and add it in the view hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you very much. But to be honest I already used this questionable method of creating a WKWebView  and it worked quite well. If you know a good instruction for creating a WKWebView programmatically, please give me a link.